# clock dissapeared from menu

Tags: 13.10, menu, time, date

As you can see from the screenshot, I am missing date and time from top menu. Is it stupid april fools joke or...?

[image: date and time]

I am clueless how to put it back. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Tried the proposed solution from the comments:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

gives me:

```
indicator-datetime is already the newest version.
```

when i paste as normal user the command for the clock:

```
janipav@janipav-energy:~$ /usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
```

gives me

```
bash: /usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I don't have 13.10 to test this but if you take a look at [This question on Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/234377) it may help.  My solution worked on 12.04.

Comment: did not help me. See my results in the edit...

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**
In the meantime, Ubuntu offered me update of linux kernel, so I rebooted the machine. Now everything runs ok, but still: Was it joke well played or a bug?

Comment: May be an April fool's prank! ;-)

Comment: It's the re-logging in to Unity that fixed it, not the new kernel. I have encountered several issues like that with the Unity in 13.10 which are solved by logging out and in again.