# Input method icon invisible in Radiance theme

Tags: unity, 13.10, icons, radiance

As I am Czech, but I also need to write in English, I am switching through Czech keyboard layout and English keyboard layout. In Ambiance I could see what keyboard layout am I using simply by looking at the icon:

[image: icon]

(Please note, I am re-using screen from my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441834/clock-dissapeared-from-menu) but I feel you will get the idea)

After switching to Radiance, the icon looks kinda invisible:

[image: icon]

Is there a way to change the icon? Or should I apply the simplest solution, which is (quietly weep and) switch back to Ambiance?

**EDIT**
After reboot of machine everything seemed ok:

[image: icon fixed]

But today, I turned on my computer from shutdown and I am back on "invisible" icon. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Unity Tweak Tool, go to Icons tab and change icon theme from ubuntu-mono-dark to ubuntu-mono-light or the other way round. To install ubuntu tweak tool, open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: In the meantime I upgraded to 14.10 which also seems like solution, but answer "upgrade to newest Ubuntu" would be really lame. I believe this would help